# HTML Comment Box automatically not increasing height

Tags: javascript, html, css

I got the HTML code for creating a comment box from the internet. It works perfectly fine but as the number of comments increases, the comments appear on the text present below it. I want the comments to show up in a specific box with a scroll-bar. I used div but still the comments just flow out of the box. I tried whatever I could but I'm really not finding the solution.

Given below is the css that I am using -

```
    <style>
    #details {
    display : block;
    background-color : #9494FF;
    height : 20px;
    width : 130px;
    padding : 4px;
    border-radius : 10px;
    border : 1px solid black;
    cursor : pointer;
    }

    summary::-webkit-details-marker {
        display: none
        }

    textarea {
    resize : none;
    }

    #para {
    display : block;
    overflow : none;
    height : 200px;
    width : 100%;
    resize : none;
    }

</style>
```

And here is the code -

```
<ul>

<form>
<textarea id="words" rows="3" cols="60">Enter Comment</textarea>
<input type="button" onclick="getwords()" value="Comment" /> <br>
<details id="details"><summary><center>View Comments</center></summary><div id="para"></div></details>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
function getwords() {
  text = words.value;
  document.getElementById("para").innerHTML += '<div>'+text
  document.getElementById("words").value = "Enter Comment"
}
</script>

</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give the wrapper div around it the property

```
overflow: scroll;
```

on your CSS-code

Comment: ' overflow : scroll ' worked perfectly. This was perfectly what I wanted. But the scroll-bar is also appearing below the box. I just want the scroll-bar present to the right.  What should I do to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the resize none property, that makes it so it will not increase in size.

```
textarea {
   resize : none; /* Remove this */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to appear a scroll bar you must change the `overflow : none` to `overflow : auto`

Answer (score 0):

**Add overflow property to para**

```
#para {
    display : block;
    overflow : auto;
    height : 200px;
    width : 100%;
    resize : none;
    }
```

**You forgot to add closing tag to the JS string**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function getwords() {
  text = words.value;
  document.getElementById("para").innerHTML += '<div>'+ text + '</div>' 
  document.getElementById("words").value = "Enter Comment"
}
</script>
```